# Need a good strategy for going about building a mobile app

Tags: android, iphone

I am planning to build a mobile application which streams data from a server. The data is supposed to be some local news. I should have the flexibility to update the news from an HTML interface. Can someone guide on the best methods to adopt ?

Should i buy some server space from some provider like Amazon Web Services or something.(Any recommendations ?) Just in case the app grows, i guess i might have to increase the number of servers. Will i have to write code accordingly or something ? i am not sure. Is there any recommended scripting for the server side implementation.

Comment: This is a perfectly legitimate question. This question doesn't deserve a -3 rating just because some trigger happy users could not hold themselves back...

Comment: Not really, it's broad, and vague. Anything that asks for a "best" mechanism when the answer isn't quantifiable is also suspect. I didn't vote it down, but it's not a great fit.

Comment: Yea. My mistake. I have some very fundamental doubts. Should i buy some server space from some provider like Amazon Web Services or something.(Any recommendations ?) Just in case the app grows, i guess i might have to increase the number of servers. Will i have to write code accordingly or something ? i am not sure. Is there any recommended scripting for the server side implementation.

Answer (score 2):

[Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) is probably a good choice. Its an html 5 based app framework that allows you to target multiple platforms including ios and android.

Comment: yea, guess this will help me really for compatibility with multiple platforms, but my main doubts is in the server implementation.

Comment: You should probably write a more focused question. There are innumerable more choices for the server side than for a mobile app.